# sed with regular expression

Tags: regex, sed

I am trying to replace three letter code at the end of a sequence with nothing (basically removing) with `sed` but is not working well for multiple regex pattern. Here is an example of sequences

```
GCAAAAAGTTGTATAGTCACACAACCTAGACTTATATCGTCTGCTATTCATTAG
GCAAAAAGTTGTATAGTCACACAACCTAGACTTATATCGTCTGCTATTCATTAA
GCAAAAAGTTGTATAGTCACACAACCTAGACTTATATCGTCTGCTATTCATTGA
```

When I try to use `regex` individually with `sed` it works

```
echo "GCAAAAAGTTGTATAGTCACACAACCTAGACTTATATCGTCTGCTATTCATTAG" | sed 's/TAG$//'
echo "GCAAAAAGTTGTATAGTCACACAACCTAGACTTATATCGTCTGCTATTCATTAA" | sed 's/TAA$//'
echo "GCAAAAAGTTGTATAGTCACACAACCTAGACTTATATCGTCTGCTATTCATTAG" | sed 's/TAG$//'
```

However when I try to include multiple regex it doesn't work

```
echo "GCAAAAAGTTGTATAGTCACACAACCTAGACTTATATCGTCTGCTATTCATTAG" |
sed 's/(TAG$|TAA$|TGA$)//'
```

Could somebody point to me where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use extended regex switch in sed:

```
sed -r 's/(TAG|TAA|TGA)$//'
```

OR on OSX:

```
sed -E 's/(TAG|TAA|TGA)$//'
```

Or this sed without extended regex (doesn't work on OSX though):

```
sed 's/\(TAG\|TAA\|TGA\)$//'
```

Comment: Good to know the different options on different platforms....thanks for you help...

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the RE metacharacters `|` and parens.

```
sed 's/\(TAG$\|TAA$\|TGA$\)//'
```

or you can use the portable option `-E` to prevent escaping. `-E` enable extended regular expressions, so your original command will run without any issues.

Comment: Thanks @anubhava. I didn't know. Don't have a mac handy at work but it does seems odd though. Ever since I've installed gnu-sed, I hardly ever use `bsd` variant. GNU goodness has crippled me. `:)`

Comment: I know these gnu versions make us forget about old BSD ones soon :)

Comment: @upendra You're welcome buddy! Glad we could help out!

Answer (score 2):

for non GNU sed (or with `--posix` option) where `|` is not available

If TGG is not occuring or could be included

```
sed 's/T[AG][AG]$//' YourFile
```

if not

```
sed 's/T[AG]A$//;s/TAA$//' YourFile
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, `sed` uses Basic Regular Expressions, which requires escaping parentheses and pipes:

```
sed 's/\(TAG\|TAA\|TGA\)$//'
```

Recent versions of `sed` also support the `-r` option to use Extended Regular Expressions:

```
sed -r 's/(TAG|TAA|TGA)$//'
```

Comment: Not all special characters, just the ones that come from extended RE. You don't escape `.`, `*`, `[`, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this will be that helpful for you, but if you want to remove just the last 3 characters regardless:

```
sed 's/...$//'
```

Comment: Probably not in this case as the regex that i have above is for removing the three stop codons in sequences (generally at the end of the sequence). But good to know this as well...

Answer (score 1):

`awk` can also be used if you like to try some other solution:

```
awk '{sub(/(TAG|TAA|TGA)$/,"")}1' file
```